# PSQL output html format

Tags: html, postgresql, psql

I want to add the UTF8 coding in this small code:

```
\o page_html.html --output of the psql command

\pset format html
\pset border 1
\pset charset 'utf-8'
\pset title 'Liste des employés' --note here the character 'é'
\pset tableattr align='center'
 --\pset charset 'utf-8' ?? (something like this)
SELECT jobtitle FROM employee;
\o
```

i didn't find the command charset associated to the \pset command

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a character set for psql like this:

`\encoding utf8`

Use `\encoding` without parameters to show the current setting.

Usually psql will autodetect client encoding from the locale settings (LC_CTYPE or LANG environment variables on Unix).